# Scaling image for printing

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the following code to print an image from a PictureBox.
All works great except for scaling images down if they are bigger than the print page.
Is there a method I'm missing to do this?

Screenshot, large image outside of the paper bounds:

[http://a.yfrog.com/img46/63/problemsh.png http://a.yfrog.com/img46/63/problemsh.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img46/63/problemsh.png)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddHandler PrintDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf OnPrintPage

    With PageSetupDialog1
        .Document = PrintDocument1
        .PageSettings = PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings

        If PictureEdit1.Image.Height >= PictureEdit1.Image.Width Then
            PageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.Landscape = False
        Else
            PageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.Landscape = True
        End If

    End With

    PrintDialog1.UseEXDialog = True
    PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1

    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        If PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings = PageSetupDialog1.PageSettings
            PrintDocument1.Print()

        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnPrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim img As Image = PictureEdit1.Image

    Dim sz As New SizeF(100 * img.Width / img.HorizontalResolution, 100 * img.Height / img.VerticalResolution)
    Dim p As New PointF((e.PageBounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2, (e.PageBounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, p)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
Dim sz As New SizeF(100 * img.Width / img.HorizontalResolution, 100 * img.Height / img.VerticalResolution)
```

With something like this to fit the image in the page:

```
dim ScaleFac as integer = 100
While (ScaleFac * img.Width / img.HorizontalResolution > e.PageBounds.Width or ScaleFac * img.Height / img.VerticalResolution > e.PageBounds.Height) and ScaleFac > 2
    ScaleFac -= 1
Wend
Dim sz As New SizeF(ScaleFac * img.Width / img.HorizontalResolution, ScaleFac* img.Height / img.VerticalResolution)
```

You could use algebra to solve for the proper scalefac, but I don't have time to test it and if you didn't understand what I'd done that would be a lot harder for you to debug. Pretty sure you'll see what I'm trying to do here from the just the code alone! Regards.

Comment: Works great and makes sence yes - Scalefac :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim img As Image = PictureEdit1.Image
e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, 
                     e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height)
```

is all that you will need to solve

Comment: This will fit the image to the page, but will stretch the image both ways. It does not keep the same aspect ratio and so it distorts the image. In most cases this is not desired.